# How to get back Map from .txt file use Properties?

Tags: java, properties, dictionary

This is code to write hashtable to .txt file !

```
public static void save(String filename, Map<String, String> hashtable) throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.putAll(hashtable);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    try {
       prop.store(fos, prop);
    } finally {
       fos.close();
    }
}
```

How we  getback the hashtable from that file ? 
Thanks

Comment: Remember to accept an answer that (best) helped you solve your problem. Use the green checkmark to the left of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Properties.load()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)

code example:

```
public static Properties load(String filename) {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
    Properties props = new Properties(); // The variable name must be used as props all along or must be properties
    try{
        props.load(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    return props;
}
```

---

Edit:

If you want a map back, use something like this.  (The toString is to avoid a cast - you can cast to String if you would prefer)

```
public static Map<String, String> load(String filename) {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
        myMap.put(key.toString(), props.get(key).toString());
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the very same ugly manner:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Map<String, String> load(String filename) throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    try {
        prop.load(fis);
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
    return (Map) prop;
}
```